# Apache directory and alias

Tags: apache-2.2

I have moved this from stackoverflow to serverfault due to not getting any replies.

I have created the following folder on my server:

```
MyIPAddress/var/www/webdav/calendars
```

I have added the following to my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf file:

```
Alias /webdav "/var/www/webdav"
<Directory /var/www/webdav>
        DAV On
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

# calendars
Alias /calendars "/var/www/webdav/calendars"
<Directory /var/www/webdav/calendars>
    DAV             On
    AuthType        Basic
    AuthName        "My Calendar Directory"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
    Require         valid-user
</Directory>
```

Then I try to connect to the "calendars" folder using WebDAV with the following path:

```
http://MyIPAddress/var/www/webdav/calendars
```

But that does not work.

It only works if I set up default.conf like this:

```
<Directory /webdav/var/www/webdav/calendars>
```

But I don't see why. The directory path in the second approach

```
/webdav/var/www/webdav/calendars
```

does not exist. It should be

```
/var/www/webdav/calendars
```

instead.

Does anybody see my mistake or sees why only the wrong-path-approach works?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you check if the second variant works?

Comment: @Glueon I try to connect to the directory using WebDAV.

Comment: @Glueon I have edited my post and added some info. Do you think you could have a look at it again and see if you spot anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand what Alias directive is.
Why do you specify the whole `/var/www/webdav/calendars` path in a URL?

Calendar folder should be accessible at `http://MyIPAddress/calendar` and webdav at `http://MyIPAddress/webdav` according to your alias directives.

`Alias /calendars "/var/www/webdav/calendars"` means that everything containing /calendars in URL will be taken from /var/www/webdav/calendars.

For example file `http://.../calendars/folder/bla.gif` will be served from `/var/www/webdav/calendars/folder/bla.gif`

If you do not add alias for `/calendars` then apache will search bla.gif at DocumentRoot + /folder/bla.gif.

Comment: Yes, that is right: I would like to the folder "/var/www/webdav/calendars" to be accessible as "http://MyIPAddress/calendars". That is why I have entered the alias "Alias /calendars "/var/www/webdav/calendars". How else could I tell Apache that this is my where the real path is located? Or in other words: Could you perhaps tell me how exactely how it should be done?

Comment: Hm. Then why do you wounder that http://.../var/www/webdav/calendars link does not work? It shouldn't. http://.../calendars should.
Then what is your actual problem?